# Nested ranges only working for the last range

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, nested, range

Absolute beginner here so I apologize if some terms are incorrectly used. I'm trying to run several ranges at the same time until one of them reaches the target. I tried nesting them but what happened is that only the last range was working towards the target while the others were stuck at 1.
To clarify I wanted x1 to print out 3,6,9,12.., x2 to print out 2,4,6,8.. and x3 to print out 1,2,3,4...
instead x1 and x2 printed only 1,1,1,1... and only x3 was printing correctly as 1,2,3,4,...

```
range1 = (range(0, 100000000000000000000, 3))
range2 = (range(0, 100000000000000000000, 2))
range3 = (range(0, 100000000000000000000, 1))
for x1 in range1:
    for x2 in range2:
        for x3 in range3:

            if x1 == 1358445000:
                print ("x1=", x1)
                break
            if x2 == 1358445000:
                print ("x2=", x2)
                break
            if x3 == 1358445000:
                print ("x3=", x3)
                break

            else:
                print (x1)
                print (x2)
                print (x3)
```

Comment: You need to loop them all together. See [**`zip`**](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip).

Comment: You have nested loops, that's the cause of your observations. Like Peter commented, `zip` would be a possible solution for you: `for x1, x2, x3 in zip(range, range2, range3):`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`zip` would help solving your problem as:

```
range1 = range(0, 100000000000000000000, 3)
range2 = range(0, 100000000000000000000, 2)
range3 = range(0, 100000000000000000000, 1)


for x1, x2, x3 in zip(range1, range2, range3):
    if x1 == 1358445000:
        print("x1=", x1)
        break
    if x2 == 1358445000:
        print("x2=", x2)
        break
    if x3 == 1358445000:
        print("x3=", x3)
        break
    else:
        print(x1)
        print(x2)
        print(x3)
```

note that zip iteration will stop at the shortest iterable. You might want also take a look at `zip_longest` from `itertools` package.

Comment: Don't use space before a bracket.